# A question about Quadratic residues and modulos

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I need help in understanding why :

If a is a Quadratic residue modulo $p^l$ ( $\exists x$  such that $x^2 \equiv a \mod(p^l)$ ) then its a Quadratic residue modulo p ($ \exists x$ such that $x^2 \equiv a \ mod (p)$ ).

Comment: If $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p^l}$, where $l\ge 1$, then $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure I understand why...could you please explain?

Comment: $x=a\pmod n\iff x=a+Kn$ for an integer $K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usual definition of quadratic residue goes as follows: $a$ is a quadratic residue of $m$ if $\gcd(a,m)=1$ and there exists an $x$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

Suppose that $a$ is a quadratic residue of $p^l$, where $l\ge 1$. Then $\gcd(a,p^l)=1$ and there is a $b$ such that $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p^l}$.

It follows that $\gcd(a,p)=1$. Furthermore, since $p^l$ divides $b^2-a$, it follows that $p$ divides $b^2-a,$ and therefore $b^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$. Thus by definition $a$ is a quadratic residue of $p$.

Note that, in the above argument, there is no need to assume that $p$ is prime.

*Remark*: It is more challenging to work in the opposite direction, and try to show that if $a$ is a QR of $p$, then $a$ is a QR of $p^l$. This is true for all odd primes $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $N=Mp^{l-1}$
$$x^2=a+Mp^l\Rightarrow x^2=a+Np$$